# how to find largest number in list

Tags: python, list

So i'm trying to find the third largest number/string in a list. This is the code that i have so far

```
def big(inputString):
    big1 = inputString[0]
    big2 = inputString[0]
    big3 = inputString[0]
    for char in inputString:
        if char > big1:
            big1, big2,big3 = char,big1,big2
        elif big1 > char > big2 > big3:
            big3 = char
    print('largest',big1,'second largest',big2,third largest,big3)
```

when the user inputs a list of string the out put should look like this:

```
big('abxztu')
largest z second largest x third largest u
```

but the output that i get is

```
largest z second largest x third largest b
```

Can anyone tell me where the mistake is in my code

Comment: what if big2 > char > big3?

Comment: How do you define largest number? Your code doesn't appear to account for numbers with more than one digit

Comment: Why don't use `sorted` and taking the largest according to it, `third_largest,second_largest,largest  = sorted('abxztu')[-4:-1]`

Answer (score 2):

You aren't handling the case where big2 > char > big3.

Also instead of this manual brute force approach, you can just sort the string and then print the characters in any order.

```
s = sorted('abxztu')
print s # ['a', 'b', 't', 'u', 'x', 'z']
```

Now print them from the tail or if you want reverse s and print them from the head.

Even a better answer suggested by @Chris_Rands is to use heapq.nlargest.

```
print heapq.nlargest(3, 'abxztu') #['z', 'x', 'u']
```

Comment: `heapq.nlargest` is better than sorted for this

Comment: @Chris_Rands I agree. This solution deserves to be an answer instead of a comment :)

Comment: Was suggesting you add it to your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do this:

```
def big(inputString):
    l = sorted(list(inputString)) #Turning the input into a list and sorting it
    l = l[::-1] #Reversing the list
    print(l[0],l[1],l[2]) #Printing out the first three element of the list
```

This is a example of a test run:

```
>>> big("abc")
c b a
```

---

Edit 1

Another example of a test run:

```
>>> big("helloworld")
w r o
```

Comment: Your test case doesn't really show much, it's probably better to use a test that at least has 4 items and that doesn't just need reversed without sorting, try the OPs input: `'abxztu'`

Comment: Thx for the comment Nick, I have now edited my answer by adding a example of using a more complex string

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in `sorted` to sort a list. `sorted` accepts a `reverse` parameter (a boolean) so you can sort the list descending.

You can even pass a string to `sorted` and it will sort the individual characters into a list.

To get the third, or second, or nth biggest item in the list, just sort the list in descending order then call that item, e.g. `obj[0]` for the largest item, `obj[1]` for the second-largest, etc.

Let's put it together:

```
""" Returns nth largest object from string or list """
def nth_largest(obj, n=1):
    obj = sorted(obj, reverse=True)
    return obj[n-1]

>>> nth_largest('abxztu', 3)
'u'
```

Comment: @TobySpeight My bad, I figured this was self-explanatory in context but as you say it's better to provide the surrounding context anyway for future searchers. Updated my answer.

Comment: That gives us only the largest number. The question is about the 3rd largest number.

Comment: @RakshaSaini I believe you're mistaken, if you read the answer again you'll see that it provides a generic solution for finding the nth largest number, and even shows it in action returning the 3rd largest number.

Answer (score 0):

One condition is missing when char is less than big1 and greater than big2

Code :

```
def big(inputString):
    big1 = inputString[0]
    big2 = inputString[0]
    big3 = inputString[0]

    for char in inputString:
        if char > big1:
            big1, big2, big3 = char, big1, big2
        elif big1 > char > big2 > big3:
            big3 = char
        elif big3 < char < big1 > big2:
            big3 = char

    print('largest',big1,'second largest',big2,'third largest',big3)
```

Answer (score 0):

For top 3 biggest:

```
import string
def bigger(s):
    l = [(i,string.ascii_letters.index(i)) for i in s]
    max1=max(l,key=lambda x: x[1])
    l.remove(max1)
    max2=max(l,key=lambda x: x[1])
    l.remove(max2)
    max3=max(l,key=lambda x: x[1])
    return '\n'.join([max1[0],max2[0],max3[0]])

print(bigger('zsabx'))
```

Output:

```
z
x
s
```

For biggest:

```
import string
def bigger(s):
    l = [(i,string.ascii_letters.index(i)) for i in s]
    max1=max(l,key=lambda x: x[1])
    return max1[0]

print(bigger('zsabx'))
```

Output:

```
z
```